# How to format the content generated from AWS Bedrock API in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-bedrock

I am using Bedrock LLAMA-2 70b API to generate content based on query asked - similar to GPT, and receiving back response from it but within a single paragraph. This is messy and difficult to read sometimes since it doesn't format nor completes it. How can I apply formatting such as recognizing bullet points, new line characters, code snippets shared and more? **Im using Nodejs for the backend with Reactjs for frontend**. Are there any existing libraries out there that can do this?

Demonstration:

> Generate Fibonacci code using Javascript

> Here is an example of how you can generate Fibonacci numbers using JavaScript: `function fibonacci(n) { if (n <= 1) { return n; } return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2); } console.log(fibonacci(5)); // Output: 5 console.log(fibonacci(8)); // Output: 21 console.log(fibonacci(13)); // Output: 89` This function uses a recursive approach to calculate the nth Fibonacci number. It starts by checking if n is less than or equal to 1, in which case the result is simply n. Otherwise, it calculates the (n-1)th and (n-2)th Fibonacci numbers using the same function, and then adds them together to get the nth Fibonacci number. You can also use a loop to calculate the Fibonacci numbers, here is an example: `function fibonacci(n) { var a = 0, b = 1, result = 0; for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { result = a + b; a = b; b = result; } return result; } console.log(fibonacci(5)); // Output: 5 console.log(fibonacci(8)); // Output: 21 console.log(fibonacci(13)); // Output: 89` This function uses a loop to calculate the Fibonacci numbers, it starts by initializing two variables a and b to 0 and 1, and then uses a loop to iterate n times, in each iteration it adds a and b together and assigns the result to a, then it assigns b to the result of the previous iteration, and at the end it returns the result. You can also use a memoized function to calculate the Fibonacci numbers, here is an example: ``` function fibonacci(n) { var memo = { 0: 0, 1: 1 }; for (var i =

As noticed above, the code generated is within a paragraph and difficult to read.

This is the API:

```
app.post('/api/chat', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const { message } = req.body; //user's query
    const fetch = await import('node-fetch');
    const url = process.env.API; //connects to lambda function

    //BedRock requestBody
    const requestBody = {
        role: "user", 
        content: message
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch.default(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
        }

        const responseJson = await response.json();
        const generation = responseJson.generation;
        
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            message: generation
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            status: 400,
            message: error
        });
    }
})
```

This is AWS Lambda function implementing the Bedrock API model via boto3 and is called when the API is activated:

```
import boto3
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    runtime= boto3.client(
        service_name = 'bedrock-runtime',
        region_name = 'us-east-2'
    )
    
    contentData = json.loads(event['body'])
    content = contentData['content']

    inputData = {
        "modelId": "meta.llama2-70b-chat-v1",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "body": {
            "prompt": content,
            "max_gen_len": 512,
            "temperature": 0.8,
            "top_p": 0.2
        }
    }
    
    try:
        response = runtime.invoke_model(body=json.dumps(inputData['body']),
                                           contentType=inputData['contentType'],
                                           modelId = inputData['modelId'],
                                           accept = inputData['accept']
                                        )
        
        response_content = response.get('body').read()
        final_response = json.loads(response_content)
        
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            'headers': {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
            "body": json.dumps(final_response)
        }
        
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': str(e)
        }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.